# How to delete number of chat in discord by python

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I would like to create a bot which can delete number of recently chat and history chat

```
import discord  
import random

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):  
        channel = message.channel.name
        restricted_channels = ["command-bot"]  

        prefix = "-"  # Replace with your prefix
        # If the message starts with the prefix
        if message.content.startswith(prefix):
            if channel in restricted_channels:  
                command = message.content[len(prefix):]  
                if command.startswith("clear"):
                    await message.delete()
```

I have try this

```
if command.startswith("clear"):
    await message.delete()
```

But it only delete the chat which have command "clear"

Answer (score 0):

First off, personally, I would change the structure/ layout of your code. This is so that it is easier to read, and easier to change and add commands/ different functions to. This is the way I have my bot setup and how I have seen many other bots setup as well:

```
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix', intents=discord.Intents.all()) # creates client


@client.event # used commonly for different events such as on_ready, on_command_error, etc...
async def on_ready():
  print('your bot is online') # basic on_ready event and print statement so you can see when your bot has gone online
```

Now that we've gone through that part, let's get onto the purge/ clear command you're trying to make. I have one in my bots which generally looks something like this:

```
@client.command() # from our client declaration earlier on at the start
@commands.has_permissions(moderate_members=True) # for if you want only certain server members to be able to clear messages. You can delete this if you'd like
async def purge(ctx, amount=2): # ctx is context. This is declared so that it will delete messages in the channel which it is used in. The default amount if none is specified in the command is set to 2 so that it will delete the command call message and the message before it
     await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount) # ctx.channel.purge is used to clear/ delete the amount of messages the user requests to be cleared/ deleted within a specific channel
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions or issues just let me know and I'll help the best I can

Comment: Worth mentioning OP has to enable message content intent in discord developer portal, the code OP sent is incomplete, so I think you can't be sure he already has it enabled. Also, slash_commands are the preferred way to write your commands now (as far as I know).

Comment: Here my complete code @Carlos :https://github.com/Namg1/discordbot/blob/main/main.py